# Updating a field in a record with a function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax, record, assign

I would like to have a function that can update a given field which I call "updateField".

But there is an error message " error: Not in scope: `f ' ". How can this be solved?

```
data Record = Record
  { a :: Int
  , b :: Int
  } deriving Show

initRecord = Record
  { a = 1
  , b = 2
  }

updateField :: Record -> (Record -> Int) -> Int -> Record
updateField rec f n = rec { f = n }
```

Comment: Why do you take an `Int` as an argument in your function?

Comment: You can not parameterize the field, or at least not like that. Often *lenses* are used for this. See https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens

Comment: Will look into that, thank you.

Comment: I want the function to take an Int because that is what is going to get replaced in the given field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently passing a function of type `Record -> Int` as the parameter of `updateField`. This could be *any* function, not just a field of `Record`, so even if passing first-class fields were allowed, what should happen if you call `updateField` with a function like `\ _rec -> 2 + 2` instead of `a` or `b`?

A simple alternative in this case is to pass a *setter* function instead:

```
updateField
  :: Record
  -> (Record -> Int -> Record)
  -> Int
  -> Record
updateField rec setField n = setField rec n

setA, setB :: Record -> Int -> Record
setA rec n = rec { a = n }
setB rec n = rec { b = n }
```

Usage:

```
updateField (updateField initRecord setA 10) setB 20
```

If you also need to get the field, pass both:

```
modifyField
  :: Record
  -> (Record -> Int)
  -> (Record -> Int -> Record)
  -> (Int -> Int)
  -> Record
modifyField rec getField setField f
  = setField rec (f (getField rec))
```

```
modifyField
  (modifyField initRecord a setA (+ 1))
  b
  setB
  (* 2)
```

Of course, this is somewhat error-prone, because you must pass both `a` and `setA` at the call site, or `b` and `setB` &c., and they must match. The standard approach to this is to bundle the getter and setter together into a first-class accessor called a *lens* (or more generally an *optic*):

```
-- Required to pass a ‘Lens’ as an argument,
-- since it’s polymorphic.
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Control.Lens (Lens', set)

data Record = Record
  { a :: Int
  , b :: Int
  } deriving Show

-- ‘fieldA’ and ‘fieldB’ are first-class accessors of a
-- field of type ‘Int’ within a structure of type ‘Record’.
fieldA, fieldB :: Lens' Record Int

-- Equivalent to this function type:
--   :: (Functor f) => (Int -> f Int) -> Record -> f Record

-- Basically: extract the value, run a function on it,
-- and reconstitute the result.
fieldA f r = fmap (\ a' -> r { a = a' }) (f (a r))
fieldB f r = fmap (\ b' -> r { b = b' }) (f (b r))

initRecord :: Record
initRecord = Record
  { a = 1
  , b = 2
  }

updateField :: Record -> Lens' Record Int -> Int -> Record
updateField rec f n = set f n rec
```

You use `set` to set the field, `view` to get it, and `over` to apply a function to it.

```
view fieldA (updateField initRecord fieldA 10)
-- =
a (initRecord { a = 10 })
-- =
10
```

Since lenses are completely mechanical, they are often derived automatically using Template Haskell, conventionally by prefixing the actual fields with `_` and deriving lenses without that prefix:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens.TH (makeLenses)

data Record = Record
  { _a :: Int
  , _b :: Int
  } deriving Show

makeLenses ''Record

-- Generated code:
--
-- a, b :: Lens' Record Int
-- a f r = fmap (\ a' -> r { _a = a' }) (f (_a r))
-- b f r = fmap (\ b' -> r { _b = b' }) (f (_b r))
```

```
view a (updateField initRecord a 10)
-- =
_a (initRecord { _a = 10 })
-- =
10
```

In fact, `updateField` and `modifyField` are now redundant, since you can just use `set` and `over` from `lens`:

```
view a $ over b (* 10) $ set a 5 initRecord
```

Optics are *probably* overkill in this scenario, but they have many other advantages in larger examples, since they let you do all kinds of accesses and traversals of complex nested data structures without having to manually take apart and put back together records, so they’re well worth adding to your Haskell repertoire at some point. The `lens` package defines many operator symbols for every conceivable use case, but even using the basic named functions like `view`, `set`, `over`, `at`, and so on will get you a long way. For a smaller dependency, there’s also `microlens` as a good alternative.